# AudioInputStream.skip() skips too many bytes

Tags: audio, streaming, byte, buffer

```
AudioInputStream in= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
AudioInputStream din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);

AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat();
long startTime = 180;   //Time in Seconds

long nBytesToStart = (long) (startTime*targetFormat.getFrameRate()*targetFormat.getFrameSize());
din.skip(nBytesToStart);
```

This code operates just fine, except that too many bytes are being skipped. I cannot figure out what the problem is.

The code below is accurate, but it requires too much time to process.

```
AudioInputStream in= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
AudioInputStream din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);

byte[] data = new byte[4096];
long nBufferFramesToStart = (long) (startTime*targetFormat.getFrameRate()*targetFormat.getFrameSize()/data.length);

for(int i = 0; i < nBufferFramesToStart; i++){          //Go to this point in the audio file
    din.read(data, 0, data.length);     
}
```

What do I need to know about the AudioInputStream.skip() method? What might the problem be?

Comment: What title would you have chosen, if Stackoverflow would let you?

Comment: Problem using AudioInputStream skip method

Comment: You should be able to use the "edit" link at the bottom of the post to update it.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not like people using "problem" in titles - describe the problem, not that you have one, as that doesn't help people scanning unanswered questions. I've had a go making a better one, and [please review this article on how to word titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648).

Comment: "AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat();" I don;t believe such a thing exists so depending on how you define the format it might miss the number of bytes